# Phonegap retrieve data from two table in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a task to retrieve data from two tables, from table one: `name,firstname,lastname` and also retrieve their `cities` from a second table. In the second table I have foreign key as table one's id as tbl_id in second table. please reply me and advice me is joinquery support or not in phonegap.

Comment: Joins are indeed supported, and use the standard SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just use websql join query

```
tx.executeSql( 'SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.primary = table2.foreign',
[],nullHandler,errorHandler);
},errorHandler,successCallBack);
```

In sucessCallback Function query results will be returned.
For more understanding of webSql database look into [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)

Its in the phongap documentation how to implement local database in mobile [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Database)

Comment: can  you tell me what is websql?is supported in phonegap?

Comment: @user2470620 see my edit implement local database and execute queries like [this](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/) got it ?